# Iterate random integers into an Array

Tags: java, arrays

Hello everyone I am trying to Iterate trough an Array and fill each Array element with a random value. the only problem is that i get weird outputs like

> [I@4b142196

the example for this I found on [Array Example](http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-tips/data/arrays/10arrays.shtml)

but when using this in my code it won't work. Here is what I got:

```
package h05GrootsteWaarde;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

public class GetallenGenerator extends JPanel {
    public GetallenGenerator() {
    }
    int[] val = new int[21];
    Random generator = new Random();    
    public void setRandomValue() {
        for (int i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
            val[i] = generator.nextInt(201) - 100;
        }    
    }   
    public int[] getRandomValue() {     
        return val;     
    }
}
```

and here is how I call the function

```
package h05GrootsteWaarde;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Bediening extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    GetallenGenerator generator;
    private JButton bereken;
    private JTextArea veld;

    public Bediening(GetallenGenerator generator) {     
        this.generator = generator;     
        bereken = new JButton("Bereken kleinste");
        bereken.addActionListener(this);
        add(bereken);       
        veld = new JTextArea(13, 40);
        veld.setEditable(false);
        veld.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        veld.setLineWrap(true);
        add(veld);      
        generator.setRandomValue();
    }   
    public void actionPerformed ( ActionEvent e ) {     
        String hoi = " " + generator.getRandomValue();
        veld.append(hoi);       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get a strange output because array's `toString` method does not show the string containing individual members of the array; instead, it shows a strange string starting in `[I@` for arrays of primitive type `int`.

You should prepare the string manually, or call `Arrays.toString(myArray)`, like this:

```
int[] arr = generator.getRandomValue();
String arrStr = Arrays.toString(arr);
String hoi = arrStr.substring(1, arrStr.length()-1);
```

Comment: Thanks that was the problem! :) I'm new to Java so didn't know it was this easy.. the only thing that is weird that the output is like [ here random numbers] with the [] brackets any idea on how to remove this? ( so only show the numbers? )

Comment: @Reshad "didn't know it was this easy" It wasn't always that easy - the `toString` methods have been added only in Java 5. As far as removing the square brackets goes, I edited the answer to show you how it can be done.

Comment: @AmitD You are absolutely right, I edited the answer to remove it.

Comment: @Reshad That is strange. Here is a [link](http://ideone.com/vuUJm) to a working example on ideone.

Comment: hmm strange indeed! well atleast it works now :) i'll try to fix the brackets later thank you! marked your answer as the correct one ;)

Answer (score 2):

The method `generator.getRandomValue();` returns an integer array. So, if you print it, it prints the `String Representation` of your array, which you see is something like a `HashCode` for the array reference. So when you try to append it with an empty string and store it in another string, you will not get the desired result.

You can probably use is: -

```
String hoi = " " + Arrays.toString(generator.getRandomValue());
```

But why are you appending and then storing your integer array to a String reference?

If you want some random value out, then probably, you can use an `ArrayList` and use `Collections.shuffle` on that list to shuffle it. If you want a single random value, then you can fetch the `first` value. But that won't be very efficient way to get a random value. Because it will not be random enough.

Answer (score 2):

The method:

```
public int[] getRandomValue() {
    return val;
}
```

... doesn't return a random value *from* the array - it returns the array reference itself. You're seeing the `[I@4b142196` string because that's the default string representation of an array. (The first part indicates the type; the second part is a hash code.)

If you want to get a random value from the array, you'll need to actually put some randomness into `getRandomValue`...

Answer (score 0):

You are adding an `int[]` to your `JTextArea`. It displays the result of calling `toString()` on your int[] which is the memory reference.

You should probably modify your `getRandomValue()` method to something like this:

```
public String getRandomValue() {
  return Arrays.toString(val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `toString` method if you want the generated values.
Here in the code that you have wrote will give you the memory reference and not the generated values.